# Pivot is not working with the aggregate clob column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have data like below

```
ID   COUNT  COL1    COL_CLOB
12345   5      a     (HUGE_CLOB)
12345   8      b     (HUGE_CLOB)
```

I want output like below

```
 ID   a_count   a_COL_CLOB  b_COUNT b_COL_CLOB
 12345   5      (HUGE_CLOB)     8    (HUGE_CLOB)
```

I am using xmlagg in my query as COL_CLOB size is more than 4000 characters and listagg is not supporting that, pivot is not working with the aggregate clob column. Kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function to aggregate `CLOB` values:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CLOBAggregation AS OBJECT(
  value CLOB,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     CLOB
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CLOBAggregation
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := CLOBAggregation( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     CLOB
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := value;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := ctx.value;
    ELSIF ctx.value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || ctx.value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION CLOB_AGG( value CLOB )
RETURN CLOB
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING CLOBAggregation;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id NUMBER, "COUNT" NUMBER, col1 VARCHAR2(5), col_clob CLOB );

DECLARE
  p_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  p_clob := EMPTY_CLOB() || LPAD( 'a', 4000, 'a' ) || LPAD( 'a', 10, 'a' );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 12345, 5, 'a', p_clob );
  p_clob := EMPTY_CLOB() || LPAD( 'b', 4000, 'b' ) || LPAD( 'b', 10, 'b' );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 12345, 8, 'b', p_clob );
END;
/
```

You can then use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX( CASE col1 WHEN 'a' THEN "COUNT"  END ) AS a_count,
       CLOB_AGG( CASE col1 WHEN 'a' THEN col_clob END ) AS a_col_clob,
       MAX( CASE col1 WHEN 'b' THEN "COUNT"  END ) AS b_count,
       CLOB_AGG( CASE col1 WHEN 'b' THEN col_clob END ) AS b_col_clob
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID    | A_COUNT | A_COL_CLOB            | B_COUNT | B_COL_CLOB
> ----: | ------: | :-------------------- | ------: | :-------------------
> 12345 |       5 | aaaaa<4000 more>aaaaa |       8 | bbbb<4000 more>bbbbb
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8ad184e6932d96cc5937de9fb6adad4)*

Answer (score 0):

May be it's not so elegant, but it works for me sometimes, when I face CLOB column that longer then 4000 signs. The biggest problem is that we can't use group functions, but this query could be a backup way out of the situation.

```
SELECT t_pk.id
     , t1.count AS a_col_count
     , t1.col_clob AS a_col_clob
     , t2.count AS b_col_count
     , t2.col_clob AS b_col_clob
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_1) t_pk
  LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON t_pk.id = t1.id AND t1.col1 = 'a'
  LEFT JOIN table_1 t2 ON t_pk.id = t2.id AND t1.col1 = 'b';
```

Or more complex way if you need to pull data from more complex subquery instead of just one table (but in the example bellow I still use only one table just to simplify the example). Or if, in addition to “a” and “b”, we can find all the other letters of the alphabet, but we only need “a” and “b”. And the the same time, this column is not part of the index. Then it may make sense to reuse the selected data.

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT t1.id
       , CASE WHEN t1.col1 = 'a' THEN count END AS a_col_count
       , CASE WHEN t1.col1 = 'a' THEN col_clob END AS a_col_clob
       , CASE WHEN t1.col1 = 'b' THEN count END AS b_col_count
       , CASE WHEN t1.col1 = 'b' THEN col_clob END AS b_col_clob
    FROM table_1 t1
   WHERE t1.col1 IN ('a', 'b')
)
SELECT t_pk.id,
       t1.a_col_count,
       t1.a_col_clob,
       t2.a_col_count,
       t2.a_col_clob,
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) t_pk
  LEFT JOIN t t1 ON t_pk.id = t1.id
    AND (t1.count is not null OR t1.col_clob is not null)
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t_pk.id = t2.id
    AND (t2.count is not null OR t2.col_clob is not null);
```